# Moving background overlapping sprites in HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

I just added an auto-moving background to my html5 canvas js car game. The  two car sprites I have should be on top of the background, which is a road on my komodo edit (but starry night for this question). Unfortunately, the background is overlapping the two sprites. Anyone know how to put the background in the *background* of the canvas? Thanks in advance.

Code: http://jsbin.com/vayizelabo/2/edit

Answer (score 1):

There's a simple fix!

Replace your 2 animation loops with one `requestAnimationFrame` loop.

Then in that requestAnimationFrame loop:

1. Draw the background.
2. Draw the cars.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble, but you specify a bit more, with code? I'm a beginner in coding and got most of this from a tutorial.